# How to ask for Google Calendar consent after an action has happened instead of after signing up

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, python-social-auth

Context: 
I am building a Django project where users can sign in with google and python-social-auth is helping me do so. I am building a website where people can schedule events. So I thought of adding a new feature where when someone schedules an event with another person, it's going to schedule that event in both of the peoples' calendars if they are signed in with google.

The actual problem: 
When someone signs up with google on my site, it asks them to pick an account and immediately asks for consent to their google calendar. I am worried that for a newcomer on my site this may scare them, so what I would like instead is if consent to their google calendar is only asked IF they schedule an event. Is there a way to do this?

And as an extension to the question, should I ask for consent as soon as someone signs up or should I do it when they schedule an event.

Comment: But then how will the *receiver* (the person that is not making the appointment) give his/her consent?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good question, that's something I was thinking about prior to this question which is why I added the extension to the question to make sure this is even a good idea to begin with. I'm thinking that maybe if someone schedules an event and the receiver hasn't given the appropriate permissions to the website, it'll only schedule the event with the person who's given the consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requesting user permission to access user data or other resources, you can request all scopes up-front in the initial request or request scopes only as needed, using incremental authorization. Using incremental authorization, your app initially requests only the scopes required to start your app, then requests additional scopes as new permissions are required, in a context that identifies the reason for the request to the user.

[Requesting additional permissions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth)

This link might help i am not a django developer [python lib](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#incrementalAuth)

```
var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
    {'scope': 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'});

googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
googleUser.grant(options).then(
function(success){
  console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
},
function(fail){
  alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
});
```

Comment: I realized from this article that I would need to find a way to add additional scope through python-social-auth, which led me to this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454957/how-can-i-ask-for-different-permissions-from-facebook-at-different-times

Thanks for the help.