# Django - social_auth - How could I separate social_auth_facebook_scope to request different scope

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am a new web developer using the Django framework and I try to set multiple scopes for social_auth_facebook_scope in the Django framework.

What I have done is ref from this link: [How can I ask for different permissions from facebook at different times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454957/how-can-i-ask-for-different-permissions-from-facebook-at-different-times)

But I didn't know how to do it so

First,I put the **FACEBOOK_SCOPE** and **FACEBOOK_CUSTOM_SCOPE** in the **setting.py** file

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'user_link']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_CUSTOM_SCOPE = ['instragram_basic']
```

Second, I don't know where to put this code in.

```
class CustomFacebookOAuth2(FacebookOAuth2) :
  name = 'facebook-custom'
```

Is it have to use in views.py or apps.py, I don't have any ideas.

Next, I want my 2 buttons to separate each request

- First button is to log in with Facebook only
- Second button is to request permission for an Instagram business account
  so how do I config in my HTML file

Now what I am config is set the URL to call Facebook-custom to request different scope but it doesn't work and return Error pages not found

`http://localhost:8000/social-auth/login/facebook-custom/`

Instagram business Account HTML

```
class="nav-link" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook-custom' %}">Instragram business account
```

How can I fix it, Anyone has an idea.